# Binary operations on doubles in C

Tags: c, binary, double

I'm working on a high speed computing problem for a large scale simulation. In order to speed up the process I wish to make a couple of optimizations, one of which is to compute the absolute value of a double in only a couple of cycles without jumps.

My idea was, that 64-Bit double values are represented with a 1-Bit sign Bit, an 11-Bit exponent and a 52-Bit Mantissa. So a double value XOR-ed with a mask:
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 would yield the desired result:

```
double abs(double x) {
    double mask = -0.0e0;
    return x^mask;
}
```

Now obviously there are few reason one would need binary operations on doubles, so naturally the compiler throws an error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary ^ (have ‘double’ and ‘double’)
```

I was wondering whether there was any way to make this work in a fast fashion, since I didn't wish to convert the whole thing into a char-array and back as was suggested elsewhere. That would sort of defeat the purpose of fast computing.

I'm thankful for all help...

Comment: So 1 + 8 + 23 = 64. Okay, I've learnt something new today.

Comment: Apart from that, you'll need to type-pun the `double` through an union with an integer of the appropriate width; the rest is left to you as an exercise. **Wait, no.** Don't worry about "optimization" yet. How do you know this will be faster than the stock `abs()` that comes with the standard library? Have you benchmarked this? (Hint: no, it won't, and no, you haven't.)

Comment: I agree that benchmarking is critical and that it seems unlikely to be a significant improvement on the stock `abs`. But they won't be able to benchmark it until they've implemented it....

Comment: If your trying to optimize such a trivial function as `abs`, your probably doing it wrong...

Comment: Somehow alias the double with a suitable 64-bit integer.  You can use union or casting pointers and probably one or two other ways.

Comment: ok, apart from the fact that I accidentally confused single with double precision the problem still is the same, just add or delete a couple of zeros... and yes I have benchmarked one hell of a lot of different stuff and already achieved an overall speedup of 37% over standard library functions, the abs() function is just one I happened to get stuck with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variation on @Artur:
.. Use matching sized integer.
.. Initialize union with double.  Not faster, but tighter.

```
#include <stdint.h>
double Abs_double(double d) {
  union {
    double d;
    uint64_t u64;
  } u = {d};
  u.u64 &= ~( (uint64_t) 1 << 63);
  return u.d;
}
```

Note: I'd stay with `fabs()` unless profiling showed other solutions faster.

Comment: I'll give it a try and give feedback here, I'll need to read up on unions... thanks ^^

Comment: Ok, here we are, I did a couple of tests on several different machines and with two different compilers (icc and gcc) and it seems, that there is an average speedup of about 9.3% of this method over abs() from the standard libraries. The largest speedup I got was about 12%, so it does make a difference if you have to call this baby a couple of billion times during a simulation.

Comment: @Iluvatar With Stack-Overflow, "thanks-you" are better expressed by up-voting the answers that were useful.  (You need 15+ rep points to do that).  Should an answer meet your needs, "accept" the best one that does so.

Comment: @Iluvatar re-read your `abs()` comment.  `abs()` is a function for `int` and you are passing `double`.  That may invokes a lot of code.  Consider benchmarking using `fabs()` instead.  Some systems may use a macro for `abs()` and a `double` or `int` will do the |x| without a converison, but is not portable.

Comment: Yeah, I tried upvoting your comment, obviously it failed at the 15 reps... but I did find the accept button.
I also benchmarked
    fabs()
with about similar result as 
    abs()
so I'm going to stick with your solution.

Comment: It should be fastest if used as macro or inline func.

Answer (score 1):

Have not checked but this should do the job:

```
double abs(double x) 
{
    long long tmp = *((long long*)&x);
    tmp &= ~(1LL << 63);
    return *((double*)&tmp);
}
```

**Update:**

Users commenting my solution were right about problems with above code. This should be better:

```
double my_abs(double x) 
{
    union my64bits
    {
        unsigned long long a;  
        double             b;  
    };

    union my64bits tmp;
    tmp.b = x;
    tmp.a &= ~(1uLL<<63);

    return tmp.b;
}
```

Comment: Except that it invokes undefined behavior. *Twice.*

Comment: Exactly, **and** shifting into the sign bit of a signed integer. (That "twice" should have been "three times", in fact.)

Comment: It's undefined behavior to shift into the sign bit.

Comment: @H2CO3 To be frank I've never heard about it. If it was right shift of signed I would agree but left shift...hmm. Could you provide some more info about it?

Comment: it's the same case as `INT_MAX * 2` (since left shifting is identical to multiplication by 2). It relies on signed integer overflow, so it's UB. See C99 6.5.7.4.

Comment: @Artur C99 §6.5.7 p 4: "If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` × 2^`E2` is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**" (for `E1 << E2`) For a right shift though the behaviour is **implementation-defined** (C99 §6.5.7 p 5)

Comment: Thanks guys for constructive critique.

Answer (score -3):

```
double x;
int *p = (int *)&x;
*(p+1) ^= (1 << 31);
```

Comment: This is an even worse plagiarized copy of the other answer.

Comment: illuminate me. works like it should on little endian 32-bit systems with 64-bit double precision. according to standard, nothing undefined.

Comment: Did you look at the conversation in the comments to the other answer? It has undefined behavior at 3 places in these 3 lines.

Comment: @H2CO3: yes i did, but i don't get your point. therefore illuminate me, especially with the 3. reason. << works on bit patterns, the interpretation if signed or unsigned does not matter. whats undefined to cast pointers? it's low level...

Comment: It's not as low-level as you would think. Aliasing through incompatible pointer types is undefined behavior (google "strict aliasing rule"); `<<` does **not** operate on bit patterns (the operators `^`, `|`, `&` and `~` do); just read the quote from the standard.