# Create double by appending binary representations of two ints

Tags: c, binary, double, bit-manipulation, arc4random

I'm trying to create a `double` by appending the binary representations of two `int`s. This is what I have now:

```
int i = arc4random();
*(&i+1) = arc4random();
double d = *(double*)&i;
```

I hoped the `double` pointer would also use the value in the `&i+1` address, and this is indeed the case. When I print the binary representations of `i` and `*(&i+1)` and compare them to the binary representation of `d`, d is composed by appending `*(&i+1)` and `i`. So `*(&i+1)` comes first?! Why is this the case?

**EDIT:** also take a look at the answers of Juan Catalan and Mark Segal to know what's the right way of doing what I did using unions.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! You are invoking undefined behaviour by using memory not allocated for variables.

Comment: [Binary operations on doubles in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20458125). Also keep in mind that with this scheme you could generate a `NaN`.

Comment: If you ever really need to generate a NaN, `strtod("NaN")`. `strtod("inf")` is useful, too.

Comment: Use a `union` instead. You still could generate a `NaN` But won't have memory management issues.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Can I create a double variable, converts it's address to an int pointer and set the values like that? Then I allocated the memory for the double variable, no? I'm still curious to why the *(&i+1) value is in the first part. I tried it 20 times or so and it always worked...

Comment: @JuanCatalan That's a good idea, I didn't think of that! :)

Comment: This is the whole purpose of a `union`, share a memory block among several different types. Be careful though about `sizeof(int)` you have to make sure it is half the size of the `double` in your architecture.

Comment: @JuanCatalan I did check that, and that's the case. Thanks for your help. If you put your comments in an answer, I can check it. (and you can get the credit you deserve :) )

Comment: double values are NOT two int values in a row.  please read <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format> which discusses the actual format used for a double variable in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I print the binary representations of i and *(&i+1) and compare
>   them to the binary representation of d, d is composed by appending
>   *(&i+1) and i. So *(&i+1) comes first?! Why is this the case?

the actual ordering of the bytes depends upon the 'Endian-ness' of the underlying hardware architecture.

with little Endian architecture:

```
1) the lowest address byte contains the least significant 8 bits of the total variable  
2) the highest address byte contains the most significant 8 bits of the total variable.
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `union` instead. You still could generate a NaN But won't have memory management issues.

This is the whole purpose of a `union`, share a memory block among several different types.

Make sure in your architecture `sizeof(double)` is equal to twice `sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 2):

You could either use a union, like this:

```
typedef union {
    double d;
    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
    } integers;
} double_generator;

int main(void) {
    double_generator g;
    g.integers.a = arc4random();
    g.integers.b = arc4random();

    // g.d is now a "randomly generated double"

    return 0;
}
```

Or "manually", possibly unsafely, do the job yourself:

```
int main(void) {
    double d;
    *((int *)&d) = arc4random();
    *(((int *)&d) + 1) = arc4random();
    printf("%f", d);
    return 0;
}
```

In both cases, you simply address the same memory as if it was `int` or `double`. This could generate every possible `double` value, including `NaN` or `Infinity`.

However, this code assumes that `sizeof(double)` is (at least) twice as `sizeof(int)`. If it isn't, you must introduce different code to handle that.